# Proving equidistribution

Tags: probability

We have three stochastic variables. $X\sim L(1)$, $Y_{1}\sim Exp(1)$ and $Y_{2}\sim Exp(1)$. $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are independent and equidistributed.  Note that the $L$ stands for the continuous Laplace distribution. Now our task is to prove, by using the moment generating functions, that $X$ and $Y_{1}-Y_{2}$ are equidistributed.

I started by using the definition of the moment generating function to calculate $\psi _X{(t)}$.

I get: $\psi _X{(t)}=E(e^{tX})=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{tx}f_X{(x)}dx=...calculations...=\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}$

Now I'd like to calculate $\psi _{Y_{1}-Y_{2}}(t)$. If I can show that $\psi _{Y_{1}-Y_{2}}(t)=\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}$ the proof would be complete.

I thus again start by using the definition to calculate $\psi _{Y_{1}}(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{ty_{1}}e^{-y_{1}}dy_{1}=...calculations...=\frac{1}{1-t}$

Now I try calculating $\psi _{-Y_{2}}(t)$ and this is where I run into trouble. I'm thinking it must have something to do with me getting the integral wrong.

I get the following: $\psi _{-Y_{2}}(t)=E(e^{-tY_{2}})=\int_{-\infty }^{0}e^{-ty_{2}}e^{y_{2}}dy_{2}=...calculations...=\frac{1}{1-t}$. If this integral were to converge to $\frac{1}{1+t}$ instead, the proof would be complete.

Is anyone able to see where in the integral right above I've made an error? Thanks!

Comment: you are going wrong for $Y_2$. You should integrate over $(0,\infty)$ and not $(-\infty,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $\mathbb{E}e^{tY_{1}}=f\left(t\right)$ then $\mathbb{E}e^{-tY_{2}}=f\left(-t\right)$ since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have the same distribution.

$t$ is just replaced by $-t$. That's all.